# Playframework2: Ebean and OptimisticLockException

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a problem with Ebean and update. Everything what I need is something like this:

```
public static Result cancelOrder(Long id){
Order order = Order.findByID(id);
if(order != null){
    order.canceled = true;
    order.update(id);
}
return OK();
}
```

My model:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="order")
public class Order extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String date;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public Boolean canceled;

    public Order(String date, String name){
         this.date = date;
         this.name = name;
    }
    public static Model.Finder<String,Order> find = new Model.Finder(String.class, Order.class);

    public static Order findByID(long id) {
        return find.where().eq("ID", id).findUnique();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work becouse I get exception "OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows". I found some similar problems but everything was about forms but nothing like this. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Please show the `update()` method of your `Order` class.

Comment: I don't have my own update(). I am using default by extending Model.

Comment: Your code looks pretty normal, can you show us more (whole) code ? maybe there's some other annoying mistake, something about type, or something.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem.

What happens is that ebean builds the update query in a weird way, not just using "WHERE id = ?" but "WHERE id = ? AND field1 = ? AND blabla".
And if you have a float field in the table then mysql quirks kick in, float_field = 0.1 doesn't always return true even if float_field IS 0.1, it's approximate value :/

So one solution is to convert the float fields to decimal.

Another solution is to make ebean to build update queries using only @Id... Can't figure out how or even if it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Float datatype. I've changed to Decimal datatype only in DB and defined the length using @Column notation:

@Column(columnDefinition = "Decimal(10,3)")
    public Float example;

...And It works.